# Error with MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make music play in my app and have a song play after the first one has finished but i get some errors that i cannot resolve any help?

```
public class Music {
    int count;
    String[] titles = new String[] { "title1.mp3", "title2.mp3", "title3.mp3", "title4.mp3" };

    public void GameMusic(){
        count = 0;
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.title1);
        mp.start();
    }

    void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp){
        mp.stop();
        if (count == titles.length -1) {
            count = 0;
        }
        mp.setDataSource(titles[count]);
        count++;
        mp.prepare(); 
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

The errors are on:

```
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
```

(The method create(Context, int) in the type MediaPlayer is not applicable for the arguments (Music, int)

```
    mp.setDataSource(titles[count]);
```

(Unhandled exception type IOException)

```
    mp.prepare();
```

(Unhandled exception type IOException)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you use java before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the errors might be a little cryptic but they are self-explanatory.

You need to pass a Context to GameMusic() and use it to initialize MediaPlayer:

```
public void GameMusic(Context context){
    count = 0;
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.title1);
    mp.start();
}
```

`this` only works if the class (in this case Music) extends Context, so you need to provide a Context another way.

And in onCompletion() use a try-catch block to handle the IOException:

```
try {
    mp.setDataSource(titles[count]);
    count++;
    mp.prepare(); 
    mp.start();
}
catch(IOException e) {
    // Do something when MediaPlayer fails
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Music Class is just a class and not an activity and hence the `this` passes an object and not a `context`. If this is your only music player class then you need it to extend `Activity` else you need to pass a context to it.

```
public void GameMusic(Context context){
count = 0;
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.title1);
mp.start();
}
```

And for the other two exceptions, it states that the exceptions are unhandled. so you need to use a `Try-Catch` block the handle the uncaught `IOException`.

That should solve all the errors that you are getting now.

Answer (score 1):

when setting the datasource to Mediaplayer try to use absolutepath of the music file

if it is stored in sd-card means ..try this

```
 String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                      .getAbsolutePath();

 mp.setDataSource(ExternalStorageDirectoryPath +"/"+titles[count]);
```

after calling the 
     mp.prepare();

implement the onpreparedlistner ,after get the notification for this then start the mediaplayer

```
 @Override
 public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
   mp.start();
 }
```

and handle the all kind of exception, so that u can easily track the issues.